# Wordpress Plugin Issue css and js is not loading

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress `captain slider plugin` in my channel theme I do not know why css and js are not loading. No issues with permissions any help???

These are loaded in wp-contents/plugins/captain-slider/captain-slider.php

```
function ctslider_load_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'flexslider-style',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/css/flexslider.css', array(  ), CTSLIDER_VERSION );

    wp_register_script( 'flexslider',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL .  'includes/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), CTSLIDER_VERSION, false );
    wp_register_script( 'fitvids',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/js/jquery.fitvids.js', array( 'jquery' ), CTSLIDER_VERSION, false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-style' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ctslider_load_scripts' );
```

Comment: Can you give more details on the error you encountered?

Comment: I have added the code by with css/Js uploaded but with F12 in fire fox i confirmed that css/Js is not loading

Comment: Link to website please? And: is your website accessed via SSL (i.e. HTTPS)? Are there any errors in the [browser's error console](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors#Step_3:_Diagnosis)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code appears to be totally wrong.  THe function ctslider_load_scripts() is being executed when the wp_enqueue_scripts action is fired.  So all the scripts are getting enqueued after the action fires.  This is wrong.

Don't use the action.  Just enqueue the scripts like this:

```
wp_register_style( 'flexslider-style',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/css        /flexslider.css', array(  ), CTSLIDER_VERSION );

wp_register_script( 'flexslider',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL .  'includes/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), CTSLIDER_VERSION, false );
wp_register_script( 'fitvids',  CTSLIDER_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/js/jquery.fitvids.js', array( 'jquery' ), CTSLIDER_VERSION, false );

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider-style' );
```

Comment: Nope, thanks for playing, next player please. Codex says: "[Use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to call this function, or admin_enqueue_scripts to call it on the admin side, or use login_enqueue_scripts for login screens.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)".

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I've been abusing this by doing it wrong and not realizing it.  LOL